# Fasttext aligned word vectors for translating homographs

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, fasttext, machine-translation

[Homograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) is a word that shares the same written form as another word but has a different meaning, like **right** in the sentences below:

- success is about making the **right** decisions.
- Turn **right** after the traffic light

The English word "right", in the first case is translated to Swedish as "rätt" and to "höger" in the second case. The correct translation is possible by looking at the context (surrounding words).

**Question 1.** I wonder if fasttext aligned word embedding can come to help for translating these homograph words or words with several possible translations into another language?

**[EDIT]** The goal is **not** to query the model for the right translation. The goal is to **pick** the right translation when the following information is given:

- the two (or several) possible translations options in the target language like "rätt" and "höger"
- the surrounding words in the source language

**Question 2.** I loaded the [english pre-trained vectors model](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html) and the [English **aligned** vector model](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/aligned-vectors.html). While both were trained on Wikipedia articles, I noticed that the distances between two words were sort of preserved but the size of the dataset files (wiki.en.vec vs wiki.en.align.vec) are noticeably different (1GB). Wouldn't it make sense if we only use the aligned version? What information is not captured by the aligned dataset?

Comment: fastText word embeddings are not contextual: so, for every word (regardless of the meaning), there is only one vector.
Embeddings like ELMo and BERT are contextual. So, for the word "right", there are different vectors depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Anakin87 . I will definitely take a look at ELMo and BERT. By "fastText word embeddings are not contextual", are you referring to the pre-trained datasets that are trained using skipgram model? In the ["Advanced readers: skipgram versus cbow" section](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html) it is claimed so. What am I missing? I think I didn't explain the problem properly. The goal is not to find the right translation from the model but to pick the closest translation in the **taget language** when several options are given.

Comment: Quote:

> The skipgram model learns to predict a target word thanks to a nearby word. On the other hand, the cbow model predicts the target word according to its context. The context is represented as a bag of the words contained in a fixed size window around the target word ... given the sentence '....' and the target word 'silent', a skipgram model tries to predict the target using a random close-by word, like 'subject' or 'mysteriously'. The cbow model takes all the words in a surrounding window, like {been, mysteriously, on, the}, and uses the sum of their vectors to predict the target.

Comment: I only want to say that, in fastText, the word "right" corresponds to one and only one vector. In other models, a word can correspond to some vectors, depending on the context (on the meaning). See https://www.cs.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Informatik/Dialog_Systems_and_Machine_Learning/20190705_word_embeddings.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Anakin87, very much appreciated. BERT seems to be computationally expensive and overwork for my case. ELMo seems promising but I couldn't find any pre-trained dataset to evaluate it. Any pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, I suppose it's possible that these 'aligned' vectors could help translate homographs, but still face the problem that any token only has a single vector – even if that one token has multiple meanings.

Are you assuming that you already know that `right[en]` could be translated into either `rätt[se]` or `höger[se]`, from some external table? (That is, you're not using the aligned word-vectors as the primary means of translation, just an adjunct to other methods?)

If so, one technique that might help would be to see which of `rätt[se]` or `höger[se]` is closer to other words that surround your particular instance of `right[en]`. (You might tally each's rank-closeness to every word within *n* spots of `right[en]`, or calculate their cosine-similarity to the average of the *n* words around `right[en]`, for example.)

(You could potentially even do this with *non-aligned* word vectors, if your more-precise words have multiple, alternate, non-homograph/non-polysemous translations in English. For example, to determine which sense of `right[en]` is more likely, you could use the non-aligned English word vectors for `correct[en]` and `rightward[en]` – less polysemous correlates of `rätt[se]` & `höger[se]` – to check for similarity-to-surrounding words.)

A write-up that might create other ideas is "[Linear algebraic structure of word meanings](http://www.offconvex.org/2016/07/10/embeddingspolysemy/)" which, quite surprisingly, is able to tease-out alternate meanings of homograph tokens even when the original word-vectors training was *not* word-sense-aware. (Might the 'atoms of discourse' in their model be equally findable across merged/aligned multi-language vector spaces, and then the closeness-of-context-words to different atoms a good guide to word-sense-disambiguation?)

For question 2, you imply the aligned word set is smaller in size. Have you checked if that's just because it includes fewer words? That seems the simplest explanation, and just checking which words are left out would let you know what you're losing.

Comment: Thanks @gojomo,
Right now I am trying to follow the head-first approach and only use **existing** trained dataset, tools and algorithms (fasttext, pymagnitude, etc) and not implement any new algorithm. Very interesting suggestion, currently I am summing up distances like sum(vectors.distance("höger", surroundingList )) with [pymagnitude APIs](https://github.com/plasticityai/magnitude#querying) and compare it with what I get from "rätt". What you are suggesting is to use vectors.similarity("höger", averageVec(surroundingList)) instead?

Comment: **Usage of only non-aligned vectors only:** I get how non-aligned vectors can be used but there are usually several candidates when I query a word in the dictionary which makes this method inefficient.  

**Question 2:** No, both aligned and non-aligned English vectors are 300 x 2519370. I also check this with Swedish vectors and they are both 300 x 1143273 as well.

Comment: What are the relative sizes of the `wiki.en.vec` vs `wiki.en.align.vec` files on disk? Are those each text-format? (If so, you could compare the 1st ten lines of each, and perhaps see if one or the other is specified to higher decimal precision, eg `0.217` vs `0.21783356239`, which could be a reason two different size on-disk files yield the exact same V vectors * D dimensions * 4 bytes-per-float size-in-memory after loading.)

Comment: You are right. Decimal precision was the problem. Aligned ones have only 4 digits decimal precision while not-aligned ones have 6 digits.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your response as the answer. I appreciate if you also answer the question that I asked in the first comment and assure me that I understood your suggestion correctly. :) Performance is important for me and I even consider concatenate the surrounding words and use the subword embedding of Fasttext and Glove to make it less computationally expensive.